# Why doesn't the link effect apply to all links in the post?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I'm creating a blog using Jekyll, and a theme called [Indigo](https://github.com/sergiokopplin/indigo). I decided to put on a link effect, using Sass code I found on the net. Problem is, it's not showing up on all the links.

Here's the code:

```css
      a:not(.exception) {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #222;
        font-weight: 700;
        position: relative;
      }
      a:not(.exception)::before {
        content: "";
        background-color: #0396da;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 8px;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
      a:not(.exception):hover::before {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
        <p>
          Totam dolor aperiam <a href="https://example.com">consectetur</a>. Cum
          quia itaque ut
          <a href="https://example.com">ipsum laudantium rerum</a> consequatur.
          Soluta ex <a href="https://example.com">itaque repellat quas</a>.
          Voluptas ut similique saepe voluptatem eos architecto quaerat et.
        </p>
```

Why could this happen? Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible the style changed after you visited the link?

Comment: Tested it in multiple ways, couldn´t replicate the issue. Try running in incognito, maybe one of your extension interferes.

Comment: I clicked the link, and it still looks the same.

Comment: Incognito looks the exact same.

Comment: Could you replicate the issue in a snippet?

Comment: Like... a small section of code? I don't get what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Snippet is a StackOverflow way to embed code in Questions/Answers. When asking a question or writing an answer, press button with [<>] icon or crtl + m. New window will emerge where you can type your html, css and js to recreate the page and show it to others.

Comment: Since the code is too long, I used a snippet to embed CodeSandbox.

Comment: The point of the snippet is so I can see html, css and result at same time. Here I can see the result but I can´t see the css. You dont have to post the whole project, just relevant lines. You don´t even have to define html document nor body, just paste relevant divs and relevant css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue **affects every link** that is forced to break between two lines. The cause is the way the effect is carried out, pseudo element ::before creates a single rectangle that has no way of splitting up to follow words flow. Posible solutions:

1. Make sure links never occupy more than 1 line. You can use `white-space: nowrap;`
2. Cumbersome. Using media queries split links manually for each view.
3. Redesign the effect. For example:

```css
a:not(.exception) {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(28, 191, 255) 5px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px);
}

a:not(.exception):hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(28, 191, 255) 15px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px);
}
```

```html
        <p>
            Totam dolor aperiam <a href="https://example.com">consectetur</a>. Cum
            quia itaque ut
            <a href="https://example.com">ipsum laudantium rerum</a> consequatur.
            Soluta ex <a href="https://example.com">itaque repellat quas</a>. Voluptas
            ut similique saepe voluptatem eos architecto quaerat et.
        </p>
```